# Django: How to take row wise input in Django forms?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I want to take row-wise input in Django forms.
The table is as shown in: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiEvA.png)

The rows of 'Source' field should be headings and corresponding to it should be input field belonging to 'Data' field (in html template) such that the input correspondingly goes into proper record.

Comment: Do you have a form in HTML, or a Form class? Have you *looked* at what comes out of the other side when you post a form?

Comment: I have forms specified in forms.py , which but if I render it in HTML, it will display the Field names as headings and one input box corresponding to it. Instead I want the elements in rows as heading and one input box corresponding to each of them.

Answer (score 0):

When I lay out a form using {{form.as_p}}, I get something that looks a bit like this, and which seems to match what you're asking:

[image]

If that's not what you're looking for, then you'll need to set your form out [manually, as specified in the documents.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually)  All of the form attributes - `label`, `name` and `id` are available from your `form` variable being passed back to the form - it's just a regular HTML form.  Lay it out as you want it, and then substitute in the Django variables.

The form fields here correspond to the modelFields in my `class Event` in the  `models.py` file.

Comment: The field name in ur form, which are: **Location title**, **Location code**, **title**, **picture url**, **notes**, **additional notes**, **confirmed** , **booked** are these names field headings or present in rows?
If they are field headings in table, then this is not what i want. I want them to be present in rows.

Comment: It's not quite clear what you mean by field headings (which is partly why you're getting downvoted - your question is quite vague and is mixing terminology).  Do you mean the table's column names, as declared in your `models.py` file? I've updated my answer with a clarification on what these are.

Comment: See the Image that I have included, 
Lets take that case. There "Source" and "Data" are the Field Headings.
I want my form to be like (According to image) > **Title**  -- **Input Box**  > **Price** -- **Input Box** >  **URL**  -- **Input Box** > **Rating**-- **Input Box** > **Reviews**-- **Input Box** .   Hope I'm clear now.